# How to connect backend and frontend correctly with same url in Jenkins-x

Tags: jenkins-x

I use jenkins-x to deploy front-end and back-end projects, and I want to use the same url in ingress with different paths.
The frontend uses mysite.com, and the backend uses mysite.com/api. At first, I wanted to directly modify "charts/my-project/template/ingress" to achieve the goal, but when the backend was deployed to gke, he did not Use the correct address, but use the default address of gke, and generate two addresses like ***.***.***, ***.***.***/api, I don’t Understand why this happens, is there any good way to solve this problem?

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: {{ .Values.service.name }}
          servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your frontend and your backend on the same domain like this:

```
 spec:
   rules:
   - host: mysite.com
     http:
       paths:
       - backend:
           serviceName: <your-frontend-service-name>
           servicePort: 80
         path: /
       - backend:
           serviceName: <your-backend-service-name>
           servicePort: 8080
         path: /api
```